# Link FB Comment Box With FB Page

Tags: facebook-comments

I am having fb comment box in my website.I want all comments in comment box to be display in my fb page.

Using graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids={my site url},i am able to see all comments of my site.Does anyone has idea about it.

Thanks,

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more

Comment: Comment plugin of facebook is not linked with facebook page.If some one comments using comment plugin using my website,i want same comment should be displayed on my facebook page